# Generating ECDSA SSL wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, wildcard, ecdsa

I'm struggling with generating ECDSA SSL wildcard certificate signed with my own CA.

I'm using these commands:

```
# Generates CA private key
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out server-ca.key

# Generates CA certificate
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -new -nodes -key server-ca.key -days 3650 -out server-ca.crt

# Generates private key
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out server.key

# Generates certificate signing request
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config server.conf -reqexts req_ext

# Generates certificate signed with my CA
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in server.csr -CA server-ca.crt -CAkey server-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -extfile server.conf -extensions req_ext
```

With this request configuration (server.conf):

```
[req]
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = req_dn
default_md = sha256

[req_ext]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[req_dn]
CN=domain.my

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = domain.my
DNS.2 = *.domain.my
```

When I configure Apache or nginx with generated server-ca.crt, server.key and server.crt then I'm unable to connect using HTTPS.

This is output of openssl when I try to connect:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140500060243600:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:762:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

No matter which curve I'm using, I'm always unable to connect. However, when I use RSA keys instead of ECDSA, everything works.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
ssl_certificate         server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     server.key;
ssl_trusted_certificate server-ca.crt;
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

> `openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out server-ca.key`

You must create your key pair without "-param_enc explicit".
Don't ask me why ;)

Comment: I had the same error: error:14077410
I did those changes:
-I upgraded to last nginx version: 1.7.6 (1.4.x wasn't working)
-I defined a certificate chain for the parameter: ssl_certificate server.crt;
--> First: your server PEM, and after, intermediary and ROOT CA PEM.
-I generated a keypair without param_enc explicit
-I have converted the key to p8 format with openssl "openssl pkcs8"...
-I put minimal parameters for nginx:
ssl_certificate         server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     server.key; `enter code here`(p8 key)
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

Comment: Still does not work. But I have only two certificates: server.crt and server-ca.crt.